# Map missing argument for a parameter

Tags: swift

I am maping missing argument for a parameter 'product' in separate StoreKit file. But I still get an error that my argument is missing.

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    
    startObservingPaymentQueue()
    
    fetchProducts { products in
        
        self.allPatterns = products.map { customPatterns1(product: $0) }
        
    }
}
```

Here I get a message that I am missing an argument for parameter 'product' in call

```
    import Foundation
import StoreKit

struct PatternView: Hashable {
    let id: String
    var text: String
    var image: String
    var pattern: Pattern
    var isLocked: Bool
    
init(product: SKProduct, text: String, image: String, pattern: Pattern, isLocked: Bool = true) {
    self.id = product.productIdentifier
    self.text = text
    self.image = image
    self.pattern = pattern
    self.isLocked = isLocked
    
}

}

let customPatterns1 = [
    PatternView(text: "Tornado", image: "tornado", pattern: .pattern1, isLocked: false),
    PatternView(text: "Bolt", image: "bolt", pattern: .pattern2, isLocked: false),
    PatternView(text: "Dotted", image: "aqi.medium", pattern: .pattern3, isLocked: false),
    PatternView(text: "Pulse", image: "waveform.path.ecg", pattern: .pattern4, isLocked: true),
    PatternView(text: "Fast Pulse", image: "waveform.path", pattern: .pattern5, isLocked: true),
    PatternView(text: "Heartbeat", image: "heart", pattern: .pulse, isLocked: true),
    PatternView(text: "Sparkle", image: "sparkles", pattern: .pattern7, isLocked: true),
    PatternView(text: "Flame", image: "flame", pattern: .pattern8, isLocked: true),
    PatternView(text: "Storm", image: "tropicalstorm", pattern: .pattern9, isLocked: true),
    PatternView(text: "Rain", image: "drop", pattern: .pattern10, isLocked: true),
    PatternView(text: "Heat", image: "sun.max", pattern: .pattern11, isLocked: true),
    PatternView(text: "Continuous", image: "repeat", pattern: .pattern12, isLocked: true)
]
```

Comment: yes it will. Because init of the ```PatternView``` needs a value for product parameter. Inside init use ```product: SKProduct = product```. This might fix the issue

Comment: Where exactly I should put it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to achieve, without further explanation. However if you want to initialize `PatternView` inside `customPatterns1` array and get rid of error, you should use default `nil` initializer for `product` until you assign some `product` that you fetch from server. For default initializing use this code:

```
struct PatternView: Hashable {
    let id: String?
    var text: String
    var image: String
    var pattern: Pattern
    var isLocked: Bool
    
init(product: SKProduct? = nil, text: String, image: String, pattern: Pattern, isLocked: Bool = true) {
    self.id = product?.productIdentifier
    self.text = text
    self.image = image
    self.pattern = pattern
    self.isLocked = isLocked
    
}
```

Also if I understand you correctly you basically want to combine two arrays inside `map` function. You want to combine `products` array fetched from server with `customPatterns1` array that you defined before. For that purpose I would suggest not using `map` but rather enumerated `compactMap` in which you would also get an index and check if index of your `customPatterns1` array is not out of bounds. Also when you return `nil` in `compactMap`, the object is skipped and mapping moves to next object. Here is an example:

```
var allPatternsMapped: [PatternView] = products.enumerated().compactMap { (index, element)  in
    if index < customPatterns1.count {
        let customPView = customPatterns1[index]
        return PatternView(product: element,
                           text: customPView.text,
                           image: customPView.image,
                           pattern: customPView.pattern,
                           isLocked: customPView.isLocked)
    } else {
        return nil //when returning nil in compactmap, the object skips
    }
    
}
self.allPatterns = allPatternsMapped
```

If you should have any questions about this answer, do not hesitate to ask.